# Difference between getLocalName() and getName()?

Tags: apex, describesobject

I wrote some code to get field names. I see these two different functions in the [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm). But I don't see any real time difference when I run the below code in console. How are they different?

```
for (Schema.SObjectType sObjectTypeVar : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values())
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = sObjectTypeVar.getDescribe();
    System.debug(objResult.getLocalName()+ '::'+objResult.getName());
}
```

Comment: It only matters if you have a namespace

Comment: I still see both name space in both methods...
CTO__test1__c :: CTO__test1__c

Comment: Are you running this i the org that IS the CTO Namespace?

Comment: Yes. i have name space CTO in the same org

Comment: @Eric If you have namesapce in ur org then please try. I tried in different org but still iam getting both names are same.

Comment: Not "have it" in the org set as the CTO org. Meaning the org is a DE org and you have set the namespace of the org to CTO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I get in my DE org with a namespace (for this example say NS):

```
NS__My_Test_Object__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getLocalName();
NS__My_Test_Object__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getName();
```

Debug outputs as

```
My_Test_Object__c
NS__My_Test_Object__c
```

This is in the org where I have the NS set

Check via going to:

Setup -> Create -> Packages

[image]

If you do not see CTO next to the Namespace Prefix then CTO is not local and thus localName will include CTO__

Answer (score 3):

From the [same documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) you linked in your question:

> `getLocalName`:
>   Returns the name of the field, similar to the getName method. However, if the field is part of the current namespace, **the namespace portion of the name is omitted**.

This would imply that `the getName` method would return the namespace as part of the name, regardless of what namespace you are currently working in.

Comment: I am still seeing both having same namespace in the debug statement.